# Can't execute composer.phar in shared hosting

Tags: composer-php

I've installed Composer on a shared-host (hostgator) following this guide:
https://laravel.io/forum/02-13-2014-how-to-install-laravel-on-a-hostgator-shared-server

It was installed using this command:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

When I try to run composer I get the message "/home2/georger/composer.phar: no such file or directory" although the file does exist, I can open it. Other questions that deal with this suggest moving it to /usr/local/bin but that's not an option for me.

Comment: How composer was installed? Can you post the full commands executed?

Answer (score 0):

As outlined in the installation instructions, you will need to pass it to the `php` interpreter:

```
$ php composer.phar
```

Alternatively, you might want to reconsider whether you really want to execute composer in a production environment or rather execute it during the deployment and then deploy the artifacts. In other words, you probably want to run `composer install` on the machine from which you want to deploy to the production system, and then synchronize files from there to the production system, for example, using `rsync`.

For reference, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md.